# What is the difference between Queues and team selling in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

Queues in salesforce can be used to make a bunch of users as owners to a record there by providing record level security to the users in that Queue and on the other hand in team selling also we can make users to view the record (although they are not made as owners) so, my question is what ever we are trying to achieve in team selling can also be achieved by Queues then why do we have these 2 concepts in salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Because they're for completely different things. (That's an admin/architecture question rather than coding, post these on dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ for better visibility)

Queues are for "unassigned work". Customer Support Tickets, optionally split to tier 1 and tier 2 (escalations). Leads you purchased from somewhere and now you need to to go through them, nurture them, hopefully convert. Typically you grab a case/lead/whatever from the queue, you claim ownership - it leaves the queue. It may or may not be still visible to your teammates depending on sharing rules... but typically it's "done", taken care of. If the support ticket is too tricky or you go on holidays maybe you'll need to put it back to the queue, it happens. But out of the box - it left the queue = other guys lose visibility of it.

Team selling is different. It's my opportunity, I want to reap the commission from it, I want to keep being the owner. But I recognise I need help to win it. Maybe from marketing guy or another sales rep, maybe I'll agree to 20% cut. Maybe I need in-house developer's help to prototype something that will win this client over.

Maybe we have strict data visibility rules - each country sees only this country's data - but this opportunity happens to be in some border town and I'd like to invite guy from another country's team to help because their warehouse is closer, it'd make more sense to fulfill the order from their side.

You'd make such decisions on case-by-case basis, depending on opportunity. And probably the team would be slightly different each time (or maybe it wouldn't. If you have a dedicated support rep that's doing all this client's cases - he/she could auto cascade to Opportunities and Cases, offer you some unique insight how to wiin the deal).

So it's not exactly same thing as queues where people just pick up next task out of a pile.